# Facebook graph API request returning null JSONArray

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook Graph API is returning null JSONArray. I copy pasted access token in graph API explorer. It is working there but not on mobile. It successfully returned JSON object. Following is my code

```
  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/confessionofnepaliteenagers/feed",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                       jsonArray= response.getJSONArray();

                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,message");
        parameters.putString("limit", "10");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

        System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Successfully JSON object returned code:

```
     GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(
                accessToken,
                "/confessionofnepaliteenagers/",
                new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                        jsonO = response.getJSONObject();
                    }
                });

        request.executeAsync();
        System.out.println(jsonO);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected since [`executeAsync()`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/GraphRequest/#executeAsync) will be executed asynchronously in a separate thread, i.e. your code underneath this line is not blocked.

How about you put your logging/println in the `onCompleted()` callback method? that should be called only when the request is finished and the callback is called.